# Will webdriver script compiled and run on windows will also run on ubuntu?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently I use to create and run scripts using java +eclipse+ junit+ webdriver in windows platform.Now if i shift to Ubuntu platform do i need to make any changes in configuration to run all supported browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will work.But you need to check the browser for which scripts are designed.As it may be possible that you need to do code changes for web browser drivers for respective operating system.

Also make sure that all the software's java/eclipse/junit/web driver are configured on the linux machine.

Comment: useful link http://www.linkedin.com/groups/How-run-Selenium-Webdriver-scripts-3985798.S.228332418